# Java command line arguments in --key=value format

Tags: java, command-line

Is there a smart/easy way to use command line arguments in the --key=value format? I just quickly threw together a check for args[i] to see if it contains one of my keys, then grab the value for that key and set a variable for it, but there's gotta be a better way. I can't seem to find anything good with googling, so I must be searching the wrong thing. Any ideas/insight?

Thanks!

Comment: My personal favourite piece of kit for parsing command line arguments is [JCommander](http://jcommander.org/) - it's annotation configured and [feature rich](http://jcommander.org/#Separators). But there are literally thousands of command line parsers out there... Google would have been a better option than StackOverflow.

Comment: Try [this](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/cli/CommandLine.html), but no guarantees.

Comment: this one is the best library: http://pholser.github.io/jopt-simple/

Comment: @user2684301 don't user words like "best" as they are normative. It might be your personal preference but that doesn't make it the "best". Why should the OP use it? Does it meet the requirements?

Comment: sure. jopt-simple satifies the requirements. I believe it has a cleaner more type safe API than the other similar libraries such as apache cli. Look at the example code and see if you feel the same way.

Comment: Thanks all, I checked out the command line argument parsers and found it much easier to just use the -D option. Appreciate the responses.

Comment: Isn't there any build in function comes within the JDK yet? Do we still need to implement by ourselves or use some 3rd party jar?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try the `-D` option, allows to set `key=value` pair:

run command; note there are no space between `-Dkey`

- `java -Dday=Friday -Dmonth=Jan MainClass`

In your code:

```
String day = System.getProperty("day");
String month = System.getProperty("month");
```

Comment: in case no key is set then it will return null values

Answer (score 3):

As of now, there is no way to convert `--key=value` to Map instead of String.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    HashMap<String, String> params = convertToKeyValuePair(args);

    params.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("Key : " + k + " Value : " + v));

}

private static HashMap<String, String> convertToKeyValuePair(String[] args) {

    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

    for (String arg: args) {

        String[] splitFromEqual = arg.split("=");

        String key = splitFromEqual[0].substring(2);
        String value = splitFromEqual[1];

        params.put(key, value);

    }

    return params;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This will silently use wrong values if they themselves contain equal signs. E.g. `--options=foo=bar,baz=moo` becomes `{options=foo}`. Another poor use of `split`.

Comment: based on your requirement, you can change the split character to avoid such errors.

Answer (score 0):

This transforms `String[] args` with *key=value* pairs into a `Map`. `HashMap` is used here because it allows null values.

```
package org.company;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    /**
     * Convert an array of key=value pairs into a hashmap.
     * The string "key=" maps key onto "", while just "key" maps key onto null.
     * The value may contain '=' characters, only the first "=" is a delimiter.
     * @param args command-line arguments in the key=value format (or just key= or key)
     * @param defaults a map of default values, may be null. Mappings to null are not copied to the resulting map.
     * @param allowedKeys if not null, the keys not present in this map cause an exception (and keys mapped to null are ok)
     * @return a map that maps these keys onto the corresponding values.
     */
    static private HashMap<String, String> _parseArgs(String[] args, HashMap<String, String> defaults, HashMap<String, String> allowedKeys) {
        // HashMap allows null values
        HashMap<String, String> res = new HashMap<>();
        if (defaults != null) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : defaults.entrySet()) {
                if (e.getValue() != null) {
                    res.put(e.getKey(),e.getValue());
                }
            }
        }
        for (String s: args) {
            String[] kv = s.split("=", 2);
            if (allowedKeys != null && !allowedKeys.containsKey(kv[0])) {
                throw new RuntimeException("the key "+kv[0]+" is not in allowedKeys");
            }
            res.put(kv[0], kv.length<2 ? null : kv[1]);
        }
        return res;
    }

    /**
     * Compose a map to serve as defaults and/or allowedKeys for _parseArgs().
     * The string "key=" maps key onto "" that becomes the default value for the key,
     * while just "key" maps key onto null which makes it a valid key without any default value.
     * The value may contain '=' characters, only the first "=" is a delimiter.
     * @param args Strings in "key=value" (or "key=", or just "key") format.
     * @return a map that maps these keys onto the corresponding values.
     */
    static public HashMap<String, String> defaultArgs(String... args) {
        return _parseArgs(args, null, null);
    }

    /**
     * Convert an array of strings in the "key=value" format to a map.
     * If defaults is not null, the keys not present in this map cause an exception (and keys mapped to null are ok).
     * @param args the array that main(String[]) received
     * @param defaults specifies valid keys and their default values (keys mapped to null are valid, but have no default value)
     * @return a map that maps these keys onto the corresponding values.
     */
    static public HashMap<String, String> mapOfArgs(String[] args, HashMap<String, String> defaults) {
        return _parseArgs(args, defaults, defaults);
    }
    /**
     * Convert an array of strings in the "key=value" format to a map.
     * The keys not present in defaults are always ok.
     * @param args the array that main(String[]) received
     * @param defaults if not null, specifies default values for keys (keys mapped to null are ignored)
     * @return a map that maps these keys onto the corresponding values.
     */
    static public HashMap<String, String> uncheckedMapOfArgs(String[] args, HashMap<String, String> defaults) {
        return _parseArgs(args, defaults, null);
    }

    /**
     * Test harness
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> argMap = mapOfArgs(args, defaultArgs("what=hello","who=world","print"));
        for (Map.Entry<String,String> e : argMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(""+e.getKey()+" => "+e.getValue()+";");
        }
    }

}
```

Example run:

```
$ java org.company.Main 
what => hello;
who => world;
$ java org.company.Main print=x=y
print => x=y;
what => hello;
who => world;
$ java org.company.Main who=lambdas what=rule print
print => null;
what => rule;
who => lambdas;
$ java org.company.Main who=lambdas what=rule print=
print => ;
what => rule;
who => lambdas;
$ java org.company.Main get
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: the key get is not in allowedKeys
    at org.company.Main._parseArgs(Main.java:37)
    at org.company.Main.mapOfArgs(Main.java:64)
    at org.company.Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

Above, an Exception has happened because there is no `"get"` in the defaults.

If we use `uncheckedMapOfArgs()` instead of `mapOfArgs()`:

```
$ java org.company.Main get
what => hello;
get => null;
who => world;
```